# Boot Strap Time picker

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am using "Bootstrap Timepicker (http://jdewit.github.io/bootstrap-timepicker/index.html)" for one of my project.

I am using timepicker for 2 fields. My requirement is, If I select "09:00 AM" in the first field, then the user should not have an option to select the past time (ie, "08:00 AM") and time picker range should be between 9 A.M to 6 P.M.

Can anyone please help me on this

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('#timepicker').timepicker().on('changeTime.timepicker', function(e) {
     $('#timepicker2').timepicker('setTime', $('#timepicker').val());      
 });
```